# How can I modify the tiles size in Openscales or other ways to boost the application performance

Tags: cartography, tiles, flex, openscales

I am developing an application in Flex that uses Openscales and GeoServer in order to provide a map in the background. It works but the perfs aren't really good; even if everything is on the same computer (the application, the GeoServer and the MySQL database or the shapefiles that are used by GeoServer), loading the map takes some time (~5-10s for the whole screen).

I thought that with everything local, it would be much more fluid than that. For example, when you drag the map, I'd like the map to be updated almost instantly.

In order to boost this, I tried many things on Geoserver (shapefiles, MySQL, ...) and modified many parameters but it doesn't change anything. I'm now trying to change the tiles size : I think that they are for the moment in 128x128 so I would like to change their height and width so that the app asks the server for less tiles each time the user drag the map.

My questions are:

- How do you change those width and height? I coudn't find a way to do it.
- How could I increase my app performance regarding the map?

The code that creates the map object is the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
     xmlns:os="http://openscales.org"
     xmlns:layer="org.openscales.fx.layer.*" xmlns:core="org.openscales.core.*">    
    <os:Map id="fxmap" width="100%" height="100%" resolution="0.01" maxExtent="-180,-90,180,90" projection="EPSG:4326" center="0,45">
        <os:WMSC id="mapLayers"
             name="Topp States (WMS)"
             url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms"
             layers="WorldOnMySQL:ne_10m_admin_0_countries"
             format="image/png"
             bgcolor="0x454E54" 
             projection="EPSG:4326"
             tileHeight="256"
             tileWidth="256"
             tiled="true"
             />
        <os:DragHandler/>
        <os:ClickHandler/>
        <os:WheelHandler/>
    </os:Map>
```

After that, there isn't anything useful in the script part...

I hope you can help me, and ask me if you need more information.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't heard of OpenScales before.  Looks like it overlays data from multiple sources.  http://openscales.org/